CUDA nvcc compiler from Windows PowerShell
I'm trying to compile a simple example from GitHub/cuda_samples on Windows PowerShell1:
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2024 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Jun_14_16:44:19_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2024
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.6, V12.6.20
Build cuda_12.6.r12.6/compiler.34431801_0

When I try to compile the example, I get the following error:
$ git clone https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples.git
$ cd .\cuda-samples\Samples\0_Introduction\simpleAssert\
$ nvcc -I..\..\..\Common\ .\simpleAssert.cu
simpleAssert.cu
nvcc error   : 'cudafe++' died with status 0xC0000005 (ACCESS_VIOLATION)

This error is reported in Nvidia developers' forum, but
left unresolved there.

1 I have an Nvidia GeForce RTX 3050 ( 4GB ) Laptop GPU

See following : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.vscode-pull-request-github

@jdweng how is the link related to the question?

You have to configure GitHub code before using.

I'm adding an answer based on Stefan's for more details. I took Stefan's advice and looked at the command line created in a new CUDA VS project. Here it is in its entirety (very long !)
"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.6\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_52,code=\"sm_52,compute_52\" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX64\x64" -x cu   -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.6\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.6\include"  -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug  -maxrregcount=0   --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -g  -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -Xcompiler "/Fdx64\Debug\vc143.pdb" -o C:\Users\tuna_\source\repos\CudaRuntime2\x64\Debug\kernel.cu.obj "C:\Users\tuna_\source\repos\CudaRuntime2\kernel.cu

I played around removing flags that seemed irrelevant until I came up with the ccbin flag1
$ nvcc -ccbin C:\'Program Files'\'Microsoft Visual Studio'\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.38.33130\bin\HostX64\x64 -I..\..\..\Common\ .\simpleAssert.cu
simpleAssert.cu
tmpxft_0000a6b8_00000000-10_simpleAssert.cudafe1.cpp
   Creating library a.lib and object a.exp

Compilation is fine ( a.exe generated ) and running it seems fine2 too:
$ .\a.exe
simpleAssert starting...
GPU Device 0: "Ampere" with compute capability 8.6

Launch kernel to generate assertion failures

-- Begin assert output

C:\Users\tuna_\GitHub\cuda-samples\Samples\0_Introduction\simpleAssert\simpleAssert.cu:63: block: [1,0,0], thread: [28,0,0] Assertion `gtid < N` failed.
C:\Users\tuna_\GitHub\cuda-samples\Samples\0_Introduction\simpleAssert\simpleAssert.cu:63: block: [1,0,0], thread: [29,0,0] Assertion `gtid < N` failed.
C:\Users\tuna_\GitHub\cuda-samples\Samples\0_Introduction\simpleAssert\simpleAssert.cu:63: block: [1,0,0], thread: [30,0,0] Assertion `gtid < N` failed.
C:\Users\tuna_\GitHub\cuda-samples\Samples\0_Introduction\simpleAssert\simpleAssert.cu:63: block: [1,0,0], thread: [31,0,0] Assertion `gtid < N` failed.

-- End assert output

Device assert failed as expected, CUDA error message is: device-side assert triggered

simpleAssert completed, returned OK


1 which resonates well with Stefan's answer about x64 vs. x86 stuff
2 the only thing that bothers me a bit is that the power shell is stuck after each execution

This was an error that I also faced when setting CUDA up initially, and at least personally was due to the set up of my environment variables.
As I found out through debugging some things with my VS set up, it was scanning the x86 versions of my env vars before the x64 and using those.
The quick and easy solution is to simply remove the x86 versions, and where there aren't duplicates, simply change the other env vars from x86 to x64 (careful that they actually exist though)

which settings should I change ?

@OrenIshShalom Go to your path enviroment variables and find all the ones related to CUDA (i.e. in related folders) that reference x86 and change them to x64 essentially.
